# Atomically updating shared state in Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra

### Problem:

I am planning on using cassandra as a nosql data store for my application. One of the use-cases I have is to update a user's "balance". Say the balance for each user is stored as a key UID_balance. Now if my application would like to update the balances of multiple users, how would I handle the atomicity?

I imagine, at some point the application would essentially do the following:

```
1. for each user u
2.    current_balance = read_users_balance(u);
3.    new_balance     = current_balance + delta_for_user(u);
4.    write_users_balance(u, new_balance);
5. end
```

Now, there are a couple issues here:

1. The connection to cassandra may be interrupted causing the code to update only a few users' balances.
2. Between steps 2 and 4, there might be another process that could update the user's balance and I would be updating a stale balance leaving the user's balance in a "corrupt" state.

RDBMS' solve these issues as they offer ACID properties while Cassandra doesn't. I see Cassandra very recently (October 2012) has started offering Atomic Batches. I am not sure if it's the right solution to this problem.

### Possible Solution:

This is something I brainstormed with a friend. We don't actually update the user's balance but create a record which appends the update delta to a different record. For example:

```
UID1_balance = {100}
UID1_deltas  = {10,20,-40}
```

In order to get the current balance, we simply apply the deltas to the balance. We can have an offline process that would apply the deltas to the user's balance and prune the deltas list.

This solution works and reduces the possibility of corrupt state but I believe this is an overkill. Is there a better way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest reading the paper "Building on Quicksand"  That will get you thinking in terms of accounts and they even reference the bank account example like this.  NOTE: Chase and wells fargo don't transfer money in a transaction so he explains in that article how we can do the same thing at the micro level just like the macro level ;).

This helped alot when PlayOrm for cassandra was written as well, as there is a patterns page on the PlayOrm wiki now too.

Comment: Thanks, I will check out the patterns page and the paper.

Comment: Here's a direct link to the paper: http://www-db.cs.wisc.edu/cidr/cidr2009/Paper_133.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Your initial 'read modify write' approach can't be made to work in Cassandra since there are no locks.  Cassandra counters partially solve this problem but fall short in two places for your requirements:

1. You can't do atomic batches with multiple counters, meaning you could end up with some updates applied and others not.
2. In the event of errors, you can't tell if the counter was incremented or not so could end up with inaccurate values.

That means your possible solution of storing the deltas as separate columns is the only way to get the guarantees you want, in conjunction with the atomic batches in Cassandra 1.2 (see http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/atomic-batches-in-cassandra-1-2).  Your solution is like implementing counters, where each counter lives in a row and each delta is a column.  To read, you sum up all the values for the columns in a row.

As you say, the problem here is dealing with the garbage since these delta lists will grow over time.  If there aren't too many updates that's OK but if balances are updated frequently it would get too slow to read.

Your offline process of 'garbage collection' could be made safe by reading in the deltas then atomically deleting them and adding one delta for the whole value.  Using atomic batches and a single threaded process can make this safe.

Comment: Reconciliation is not really a big problem. The issue here is, when I add deltas to individual users' balance, the process might die leaving the balances in in-consistent state. For example - the process may add deltas to 3 out of 5 records. I need to ensure that deltas are added "atomically" for all 5 users. I'm guessing the atomic batches would be my only option or implementing by own transaction / commit log that will record the state of delta updates.

Answer (score 2):

1. As Richard pointed out the best way at the moment is to use atomic batches where you update many deltas. If something goes wrong just replay the batch.
2. The other possible solution is to use ZooKeeper as a coordination and distributed locking service: http://ria101.wordpress.com/tag/zookeeper/
3. Another possible solution is to use [counters](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Counters) so you don't need to do this

   ```
   your current_balance = read_users_balance(u);
   new_balance     = current_balance + delta_for_user(u);
   ```

   because with counters you don't need to read balance before updating. http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-0-8-part-2-counters

However there is a problem with counters, they are not idempotent so if you don't receive acknowledge that your increment/decrement was successful you cannot replay that counter as it can lead to overcount.

New counters will solve that [problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4775).